# concat result value with string to select from table in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've a function

```
SELECT col_a, col_b 
FROM public.my_table
LIMIT 1
```

That returns a single row

```
    col_a    col_b
1       7     post
```

Now I need the values `7` and `post` from `col_a` and `col_b` to query another table, where `post` is concatenated with a fixed string (`gresql`).

This query works

```
WITH single_row AS 
  ( SELECT col_a, col_b 
    FROM public.my_table
    LIMIT 1
  )
SELECT * FROM 'public.postgresql' 
WHERE col_c IN (SELECT col_a FROM single_row)
```

Now I would like to substitute `post` within `public.postgresql` with the value of `col_b` in `single_row`. As such:

```
WITH single_row AS 
  ( SELECT col_a, col_b 
    FROM public.my_table
    LIMIT 1
  )
SELECT * FROM ||'public.'||(SELECT col_b FROM single_row)||'gresql' 
WHERE col_c IN (SELECT col_a FROM single_row)
```

But this approach doesn't work. 
Any help or advice is much appreciated.

Comment: You need dynamic SQL (in a PL/pgSQL function) for this. But it sounds like a horrible database design.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will try it. I see the query more as a clever usage of an existing database for a different purpose..